# What is the rule that describes sufficiently large groups will have bad actors?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, terminology, statistics

I once heard of a rule/law/number that described any group sufficiently large enough will have "bad" people in it. It is most often used to describe how online communities will have to deal with trolls once they get popular enough.

I can not seem to find it again, does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Could it be anything to do with "[Dunbar's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_number)"?

Comment: Hmm that's really close, I don't think that's quite what I was thinking of though..